# Excel solver in MATLAB Optimization toolbox

Tags: excel, matlab, simulink

I have time-series data in Excel as follows.

[image: enter image description here]]

```
A: Sampling time (Ts)
B: w[t] = Fn  (n is Row number)
C: w[t-1] = B(n-1)
D: x = w[t] - 0.7 = Fn - 0.7
E: 0.2 * w[t-1] = 0.2 * B(n-1)
F: By Changing Variable Cells: w[t]
G: Set Objective: (x - y)^2
```

I would like to create the Simulink model. I found I have to use "fminsearch" function in Optimization toolbox and I have to use "MATLAB Function" block to use "fminsearch" because there is no Simulink blocks for Optimization toolbox.
Seeing explanation of "fminsearch", I have to define objective functions like 
  fun = @(x) x^2
In this case, I can define object function using w. However I would like to describe the object function using x and y. (In this case, (x - y)^2).
Could you please tell me how to create Simulink model?
Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If this is your question: You can create an anonymous function with more than one variable, for example `fun = @(x) (x(1)-x(2))^2` where `x(1)` = x and `x(2)` = y. But I don't understand why `fminsearch` is useful here, you will reach a minimum everytime that `x==y`.

Comment: **What** are you trying to model in Simulink?  What inputs do you intend to pass to the Simulink block's that you use?  Over what period (of past data) do you intend performing an optimization?  At each time step, what do you expect to be the output from the model?  As indicated by @obchardon, the description you've currently given doesn't require any optimization.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. That is just simple example. As you stated, in my case, you can easily calculate w. My qestion is how you create the simulink model that is equivalent to Excel solver that I showed. Actually the Excel model is very complicated.

Comment: In the excel, I found there is mistake. x(w) = w[t] - 0.7, y(w) = 0.2 * w[t - 1].

Comment: I will create Optimization block using "MATLAB Function" block. This block's inputs are x and y. Output is w that makes (x - y)^2 minimum.

Comment: You haven't shown an optimization problem.  If `x` and `y` are inputs then the `w` that minimizes `(x-y)^2` is simply `w = y + 0.7`.  You don't need Solver or any other optimizer to solve that.

Comment: Thank you , Phil. The excel showed simple example. As you said. you can easily solve an equation for w. The actual model I am struggling is more complicated. My goal is to create Simulink model that is equivalent to Excel solver.

Comment: How is it equivalent to Excel's Solver?  You need to give us a specific case, showing your actual data and your expected results before we can help you.